# Can't iterate over a Published<[String]>.Publisher in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a way around this? Or a nicer way to declare de `@Published` var in the procol.

```swift
import SwiftUI

protocol ViewModelProtocol: ObservableObject {
    var items: Published<[String]>.Publisher { get }
}

class MyViewModel: ViewModelProtocol {
    var items: Published<[String]>.Publisher { $someItems }
    @Published var someItems = [String]()
}

struct MyView<SomeViewModel>: View where SomeViewModel: ViewModelProtocol {
    @StateObject var viewModel: SomeViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.items, id:\.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be much simpler than that. Even by not making explicit in the procotol, the `@Published` variable from the ViewModel worked as expected in the View.

```swift
import SwiftUI

protocol ViewModelProtocol: ObservableObject {
    var items: [String] { get }
}

class MyViewModel: ViewModelProtocol {
    @Published var items = [String]()
}

struct MyView<SomeViewModel>: View where SomeViewModel: ViewModelProtocol {
    @StateObject var viewModel: SomeViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.items, id:\.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```